# Allow only one product purchase for a specific product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I want to limit the number of times a user can purchase a product from a particular category. I have this code ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957394/woocommerce-users-able-to-buy-a-product-only-once)) in function.php that limits the whole store to one time purchase.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation','rei_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation',20, 2);
function rei_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation($valid, $product_id){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product_id)) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Error message here', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        $valid = false;
    }
    return $valid;
}
```

and I need to add a condition that the code will only apply to products from a particular category (by category name or ID).

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code, you will have to replace `t-shirt` by your product category *(name, slug or ID)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation','filter_add_to_cart_validation',20, 2);
function filter_add_to_cart_validation($valid, $product_id){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product_id) 
    && has_term( array('t-shirt'), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Error message here', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        $valid = false;
    }
    return $valid;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

if you need to exclude the product category you can add a `!` before `has_term()` like:

```
 && ! has_term( array('t-shirt'), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
```