# woocommerce - validate items in cart page before proceed to checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm validating the maximum number of products a user can buy per day.
I could limit the number of products by `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` and `woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update` and it works fine.

the problem is when the user increases the quantity of a product without pressing the "recalculate the cart" button and after that press the "proceed to checkout" button, there will be no warning or error, I know the cart is not get updated but is there a way to show a warning to the user about the number of products in the cart, even when the user does not press recalculate button?

Update:
if the user is guest and login to site after placing his orders `woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update` and `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` wont fire.

how can I check the quantity of products and redirect him to the cart page (if needed) and show an error before allowing him to enter the checkout page?

Comment: The hook you are looking for is `woocommerce_check_cart_items`, see second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68007576/11987538) OR https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A11987538+woocommerce_check_cart_items

Comment: @7uc1f3r thanks! that answer was exactly what I needed.