# Prevent guest users from ordering a product multiple times in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

What I'm trying to do is utilize a code in my child theme's functions.php to block guests from ordering a specific product again. If they had a specific product_id in their cart (that they've ordered before), they would be redirected to a specific url instead of the order being completed.

Our website uses phone number (without a zero in the first digit) as username and to make the order process as simple as possible, the user is not required to login during checkout.

We're trying to find a way **to check if the billing_phone** is an existing username, then checking if the user_id have bought specific product(s) before. If they did, trying to prevent that and redirect them to specific url, **after they click place order button on checkout page.**

---

Inspired by:

- [How to avoid buying the same product again in WooCommerce by adding products to the cart as a guest and logging in during checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68007576/11987538)
- [Woocommerce After an Order Before Payment Hook](https://www.hungred.com/how-to/woocommerce-order-payment-hook)

We tried to construct this piece of code, but without success. The order was not prevented from repeating:

```php
function action_woocommerce_check_cart_items() {
    
  // Retrieve the current user from billing_phone
    
      // get all the order data
      $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
  
      //get the user phone from the order
      $order_phone = $order->billing_phone;
  
      //phone without zero in first digit
      $phone_nozero = substr($order_phone, 1);
      
      //gets user_id using phone number and saves it to $current_user
      $current_user = get_user_by('login', $phone_nozero);
    
    
    // Initialize
    $flag = false;
    
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        $product_id = "916";

        // Checks if a user (by email or ID or both) has bought an item
        if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product_id ) ) {
            // Flag becomes true
            $flag = true;
            
            // Break loop
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // True
    if ( $flag ) {
//Here, we likely require a code to prevent the order from being completed.

//redirect to specific url

        wp_redirect( 'https://myspecificurl.com' );
    }
}  

//hook for after clicking place order button. inspired by : 

add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order' , 'action_woocommerce_check_cart_items', 1, 1 );
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code attempt contains multiple mistakes, so some remarks:

- The `woocommerce_new_order` will be executed on newly created order event, and is therefore 'too late' for your question
- Use the `woocommerce_check_cart_items` action hook instead
- `$order->billing_phone` is since WooCommerce 3.0 replaced with `$order->get_billing_phone()` but does not apply in this case. This is because the `$order` object is only known after the order is placed, we will use `WC()->session->get( 'customer' )` instead
- You mention that the username is based on a phone number, but your question is about "only for guests". Guests do not have a username
- In your code attempt you only check for 1 product ID (916), while order(s) usually consist of several different products
- The `wc_customer_bought_product()` function only applies to users with an account. So we will have to use/write of a custom function, which is based on the existing `wc_customer_bought_product()` function
- Use `wp_safe_redirect()` vs `wp_redirect()`

So you get:

```php
function has_bought_items_by_phone_number( $phone_number, $product_ids ) {
    global $wpdb;
    
    $product_ids = is_array( $product_ids ) ? implode( ',', $product_ids ) : $product_ids;

    $line_meta_value = $product_ids != 0 ? 'AND woim.meta_value IN (' . $product_ids . ')' : 'AND woim.meta_value != 0';

    // Count the number of products
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT COUNT(p.ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi ON p.ID = woi.order_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-processing' )
        AND pm.meta_key = '_billing_phone'
        AND pm.meta_value = '$phone_number'
        AND woim.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' ) $line_meta_value 
    " );

    // Return true if count is higher than 0 (or false)
    return $count > 0 ? true : false;
}

function action_woocommerce_check_cart_items() {
    // Only for guests
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return;

    // Get session
    $customer = WC()->session->get( 'customer' );

    // NOT empty phone field
    if ( ! empty( $customer['phone'] ) ) {
        // Sanatize
        $phone_number = wc_sanitize_phone_number( $customer['phone'] );
        
        // WC Cart NOT null
        if ( ! is_null( WC()->cart ) ) {
            // Initialize (do not change)
            $product_ids = array();
            
            // Loop through cart contents
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $cart_item ) {
                // Get product ID and push to array
                $product_ids[] = $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ? $cart_item['variation_id'] : $cart_item['product_id'];
            }
            
            // NOT empty
            if ( ! empty ( $product_ids ) ) {
                // Call function, and if true
                if ( has_bought_items_by_phone_number( $phone_number, $product_ids ) ) {
                    // Performs a safe redirect
                    wp_safe_redirect( 'https://yoursite.com/custom-url-1' );
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}   
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items' , 'action_woocommerce_check_cart_items', 10 );
```

---

**Note 1)** to apply this action (the redirect) only **after they click place order button on checkout page** would require using the `woocommerce_checkout_process` hook opposite the `woocommerce_check_cart_items` hook.

Because with my current answer, this will only happen in certain cases, if the phone number is not (yet) known.

However, **the redirect would then display an error message and not be executed.** So if you still want this, you should replace the redirect by displaying a message, which then contains the link to the page

---

**Note 2)** my answer will be applied to **ALL products**, to only apply this to specific products:

Replace:

```php
if ( ! is_null( WC()->cart ) ) {
    // Initialize (do not change)
    $product_ids = array();
    
    // Loop through cart contents
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $cart_item ) {
        // Get product ID and push to array
        $product_ids[] = $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ? $cart_item['variation_id'] : $cart_item['product_id'];
    }
```

With:

```php
// WC Cart NOT null
if ( ! is_null( WC()->cart ) ) {
    // Specific product IDs
    $specific_product_ids = array( 30, 823, 53, 57 );

    // Initialize (do not change)
    $product_ids = array();

    // Loop through cart contents
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $cart_item ) {
        // Get product ID
        $product_id = $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ? $cart_item['variation_id'] : $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Checks if a value exists in an array
        if ( in_array( $product_id, $specific_product_ids ) ) {
            // Push to array
            $product_ids[] = $product_id;
        }
    }
```

---

**Note 3)** the `has_bought_items_by_phone_number()` function is based on [Check if a user has purchased specific products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46217461/11987538) answer code